# How to start sonarqube5.6.6 server

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using Sonar to prepare review report of my project.But i am getting the below exception while installing the server.[image: Any one please help me any help will be highly appreciable].Could anyone please help me any help will be highly appreciable.I referred the below link to start my installation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes

Comment: Are any of these EXE files in the corresponding paths displayed, and if so do you have read/execute access to them? If so, the space in your folder name or overall path length could be potential causes. Looking at the source in git, the script just checks for file existence to display these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the followings steps:

- Download [SonarQube 6.4](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) (this is the newest version)
- Place the zip in C:\Sonar
- Before unzipping right-click the zip-file and open the properties. Check the "Unblock" option (this is essential!).
- Unzip the zip-file in C:\Sonar, you can remove this zip file afterwards.
- Check that bin\windows-x86-x64 has 5 bat-files and a wrapper.exe file.
- Execute StartSonar.bat
- Change configuration in conf\sonar.properties
- Restart StartSonar.bat

If you have problems you should inspect the log files in \logs